# I have Json array with each of its object having dynamic attributes. I have to merge all the object into into one Json object in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I have Json array with each of its object having dynamic attributes. I have to merge all the object into one Json object in nifi with common attribute's value concatenated and other attributes as it is.

I have already tried following spec, and it is giving common attributes as array list. But I want that common attribute's value to be concatenated and I don't know how to do that. Any suggestion would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
    }
]
```

The input is like( NOTE: The attributes are dynamic so not sure always going to have these attributes)

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "Sam1",
    "lastName": "Achom1",
    "place": "Silchar1"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Saya2",
    "lastName": "Singh2",
    "place": "Macherial2",
    "Second1stAttribute": "SomeValue"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sam3",
    "lastName": "Achom3",
    "place": "Silchar3",
    "Third2ndAttribute": "SomeValue2"
  }
]
```

The output I am getting with before mentioned spec

```
{
  "firstName" : [ "Sam1", "Saya2", "Sam3" ],
  "lastName" : [ "Achom1", "Singh2", "Achom3" ],
  "place" : [ "Silchar1", "Macherial2", "Silchar3" ],
  "Second1stAttribute" : "SomeValue",
  "Third2ndAttribute" : "SomeValue2"
}
```

And Expecting the output as

```
{ "firstName" : "Sam1 Saya2 Sam3",
  "lastName" : "Achom1 Singh2 Achom3",
  "place" : "Silchar1 Mancherial2 Silchar3",
  "Second1stAttribute" : "SomeValue",
  "Third2ndAttribute" : "SomeValue2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "join" the items from your arrays. This spec will do the trick:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join(' ',@(1,&))"
    }
    }
]
```